# regex don't start with 0

Tags: regex, ssi

I've some pages with this URL

```
folder/t_01_class.shtml
```

with a sequential number

```
folder/t_02_class.shtml
folder/t_03_class.shtml
folder/t_10_class.shtml
folder/t_11_class.shtml
folder/t_12_class.shtml
folder/t_23_class.shtml
```

and I need to get variable with regex that don't considers first zero so the result should be

```
<!--#set var="page" value="2"-->
<!--#set var="page" value="3"-->
<!--#set var="page" value="10"-->
<!--#set var="page" value="11"-->
<!--#set var="page" value="12"-->
<!--#set var="page" value="23"-->
```

any suggestion

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the regex is acting against the entire page name requested in the URL, I'd suggest using something along the lines of `/t_0*([1-9]\d*)_/` and then retrieving numbered group 1.

To clarify that regex:

`//` around each end are delimiters signifying the regex itself, they are not an active part of the matching.

`t_` will match the beginning of the page

`0*` will match any leading 0's

`[1-9]\d*` will match any number starting in 1-9, and 0 or more subsequent digits (`\d` is the equivalent of `[0-9]`, and `*` after `\d` means "0 or more")

`()` around the bit above will make this a numbered group, allowing you to retrieve the match

`_` at the end is to ensure that the number match is complete

Comment: This will fail to extract the numbers with leading zeroes. You need an additional `0*` outside of the capturing group.

Comment: Indeed it would do, I saw that as soon as I posted. Thanks =]

Answer (score 2):

```
[1-9][0-9]*
```

will match any integer number greater than zero, dropping leading zeroes.